How to detect when a Logitech lightspeed headset is powered on or off
I would like to leave the lightspeed USB dongle plugged into my pc at all times, and have a script change my audio output between speakers and headset when appropriate.  However I can't find a useful way to detect when the headset is powered on.
Windows 10 always sees the headset as a valid output device because the USB dongle is plugged in.  However Logitech G HUB can see when the headset is active or inactive.  I have tried finding a trigger with event viewer but there doesn't seem to be any.
Short of keeping G HUB open and visually tracking when it switches between active/inactive how could I find a trigger to run my own script for audio output switching?
Here is what it looks like in G HUB when a lightspeed device is on and off:


Does Logitech offer an API that may allow you to read this state from G Hub? I have a Plantronics headset which uses a dongle that is always connected to my computer, and the computer switches audio when I put the headset on my head and when I take it off, so this seems to me to largely be an issue of the driver/helper utility presenting this info to the OS.
